# What are the application used to test Blueooth?

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi

I have a dialog semiconductor Bluetooth device. I would like to send data from my bluetooth to some applicaion on PC. Are there any applications that detect and collects the data from my Bluetooth?. Thank you.

Comment: There are lot of applications but I think no one of them know about your device and data it sends. So you have to follow device's documentation and data protocol and write your own application.

Comment: Thank you Mike. You mean I should develop a windows application and that application should have a protocol specified in datasheet of Bluetooth right?

Comment: Yes, something like that. First you have decide (or you need to know) what kind is your device: Is it BLE or Classic? In case of BLE does it support GATT? If Classic does it support RFCOMM? Next you need to know protocols. For GATT you need to know which characteristics need to be read, write, notify. For RFCOMM which profile it supports (SPP, OBEX, other). That is the first step.

Answer (score 1):

@gandhi,
  If your question is how to sniff bluetooth packets exchanged from Dialog semiconductor and the PC, It is worth going through this URL https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Bluetooth

The wireshark logs will show detailed information on the packet exchanged, like ACL and SCO bluetooth data